# apache force me to download page

Tags: apache-2.2

I feel a bit lost, after installing apache with suexec on ubuntu12.04 on url click I'm prompted to download the page the message what I get a message what shows the following You have chosen to open which is:  application/x-httpd-php (395 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that, along with the Apache package, you've installed the PHP package and configured Apache to use PHP for .php files.

Comment: Specifically, make sure you have a handler for the `application/x-httpd-php` MIME type. There should be a `SetHandler` directive in your configuration that implements this; it will usually be enclosed in an `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` block. You'll also want  one for `application/x-httpd-php-source`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you either don't have mod_php installed, or you don't have it enabled in Apache.

`sudo apache2ctl -M | sort` should show you the currently running modules. The PHP module should be in there. If it's not, follow one of the thousand guides for installing it on your OS.

Comment: under loaded modules I have php5_module(shared)